# Bootstrap columns too close to edge of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and am struggling to get the positioning I want. The content is too close to the edge of the browser instead of being more towards the middle (see pic) I have tried some CSS which did help but still wasn't right so I took it out. I did try use max-width which made it smaller but then I couldn't get it in the centre.

[image]

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1 class="contactformch1">
         CONTACT
      </h1>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <h4>
         Heading
      </h4>
      <p>
         Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </p>
      <p>
         <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <h4>
         Heading
      </h4>
      <p>
         Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </p>
      <p>
         <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <h4>
         Heading
      </h4>
      <p>
         Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </p>
      <p>
         <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
   <h5 class="text-center">
      h3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
   </h5>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I use the padding on then col-md-12 or rather each col-md-4?

Comment: Use container as @theinarasau suggests, but I also notice you have an extra unmatched `</div>` on line 6 that you don't need, which may mess the formatting up

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't copy/paste correctly regarding the div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use the `<div class="container-fluid"` on top. If this is the case try `<div class="container"`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        ...
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    ...
```

See the effect on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/y7lAlFZfGn).

[image]

Comment: Wow, how did that happen? I just changed main-container to container as you mentioned above and it fixed it. But how?

Comment: So far I know is bootstrap only defining: `container` and `container-fluid`. You should have a closer look at their grid system.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <!-- your code here  -->
  </div>
</div>
```

you must have at least one container so then you have default padding both edges.
in case you want to have full width you may replace `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">`

Comment: Apologies, I had main-container which I left out by accident. I have edited my original post. Is there a difference between "container" that you mentioned and "main-container" as I have?

Comment: @Jonathan Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable. this is definition from bootstrap page , should and at least i have one main wrapper your entire container into one. you may refer http://getbootstrap.com/css/ under container

Comment: @Jonathan may i know what the css you use for main-container ?

Comment: I removed css and just changed main-container to container as mentioned by d4rty below and it fixed it somehow